# Should I wait for job openings or apply for the other position?

Tags: position

Recently I found a job offer in the University website and applied. The Hiring Manager replied quickly, but it appears the ad is old and there are no available positions at the moment. He suggested to wait for openings or directly apply for another position which is almost the same as the one I applied for.

Comment: Why would you *not* apply for the almost identical position?

Comment: Sorry, voting to close - Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I learn?"). Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do

Comment: You are considering applying for WHAT other position? I am voting to close on the ground that your post post is unclear, even after an edit.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off applying for the other position, if you're qualified to do either job.

If you've applied for the new, almost identical position, then you're getting your foot in the door, and the original position might happen to become available again.

Comment: @Hris if this helped you and you feel your question is now fully answered, consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246338). `:)`